# Fontawesome inside submit button

Tags: php, css

I have this line of code:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search Products', 'paralinx' ); ?>" />
```

How can I add a font awesome icon before the  "Search Products" text?

I tried using `:before` in the input field but it does not work.

Comment: `:before` and `:after` are only available on elements that can have  `content` in between an opening and a closing tag.

Comment: use button tag with type submit instead of input type submit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:before` and `:after` are only available on elements that can have  `content` in between an opening and a closing tag. `<input type=submit>` cannot have content.

Use

```
<button type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Search Products', 'paralinx' ); ?></button>
```

instead, it does allow the usage of `:before`.

Comment: Appreciate the support

Answer (score 0):

You should use :before pseudo-element with 'content' property:

```
.submit:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 background: url("icon.jpg") no-repeat;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 6px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned, this does not work on on elements that cannot have content.

Answer (score 0):

Use button tag

```
<button type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" ><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <?php esc_attr_e( 'Search Products', 'paralinx' ); ?></button>
```